# Host key in Azure Function App for Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have created two host keys(As shown in the below screen shot)

1. AccessKey
2. AccessKey02

How I can set, which one will be use for authentication?

[image]

Comment: You need not to set here. Among your hostkey  all the key will work once user will set while they would call your function you could refer this [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-manually-run-non-http#call-the-function)

Comment: Host Key commonly referred to as Function App Level keys. Keys defined at this level apply to the entire Function App. You have the ability to define Function Keys at this level, and they would allow clients to authenticate against any function. This is also where your Master Key is defined. It does't matter if you generate more host keys. Unless you revoke them they would work.

Comment: actually I want to use only "AccesKey" for authentication, not the _master key

Comment: Yes I understand, as you may know you can generate many access key so all of them can be usable unless you revoke them. Hope you got my points

Comment: Azure functions still accepting "AccessKey02" not "AccessKey" while i am calling function via Postman. Could you please suggest where I am missing?

Comment: If you dont want AccessKey02 work, please revoke it. Maybe what you want is function key?

Comment: Do you have any other questions?

Answer (score 1):

All of the key will be used to authentication.

The host key acts on the entire function app. You can use any of them for verification, if you do not want to use it for verification, then revoke it. The host key you set becomes the key to access all triggers in the function app. (All of them will work). If you want to use different authentication for different triggers, then use the function key that acts on a single trigger.

[image]